# use custom validator control to condition is that the entrance should be numbers and letters

Tags: asp.net

how i can use custom validator in this case

I want to ask the user to enter the user ID in a text box and in the hidden code I want to use `UserCustomValidate (object source, ServerValidateEventArgs args)` assigned to the `OnServerValidate` property of the `CustomValidator` control.
To require that the text entered is at least the Capital , small letters and digits and must be greater than 5  and less than 26 letters

Comment: That's quite possibly a non-negligible amount of code you're asking for there; you can read up on Custom Validators here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.ui.webcontrols.customvalidator?view=netframework-4.7.2

Comment: As a general outline, you need to add the control to your page, and then set up both the client-side (JavaScript) validation that will be run in-browser, and the server-side (.NET) validation which will run back at the server.  Using both is strongly recommended by the documentation.